# A-Frame cursor with visual feedback

Tags: aframe

The [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.4.0/components/cursor.html#adding-visual-feedback) reference this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpmpJP). However this code does not seem to work with the latest version of A-Frame v0.4.0.

What is the best practice to implement this same visual feedback in v0.4.0.

In particular I'd like to change the properties of my target entity on hover over, hover out.

This is the code that is in the Codepen:

```
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <a-mixin id="cube" geometry="primitive: box"></a-mixin>
    <a-mixin id="cube-hovered" material="color: magenta"></a-mixin>
    <a-mixin id="cube-selected" material="color: cyan"></a-mixin>
    <a-mixin id="red" material="color: red"></a-mixin>
    <a-mixin id="green" material="color: green"></a-mixin>
    <a-mixin id="blue" material="color: blue"></a-mixin>
    <a-mixin id="yellow" material="color: yellow"></a-mixin>
    <a-mixin id="sphere" geometry="primitive: sphere"></a-mixin>
  </a-assets>

  <a-entity position="0 2.2 4">
    <a-entity camera look-controls wasd-controls>
      <a-entity position="0 0 -3"
                geometry="primitive: ring; radiusOuter: 0.30;
                          radiusInner: 0.20;"
                material="color: cyan; shader: flat"
                cursor="maxDistance: 30; fuse: true">
        <a-animation begin="click" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale"
             fill="backwards" from="0.1 0.1 0.1" to="1 1 1" dur="150"></a-animation>
        <a-animation begin="fusing" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale"
             fill="forwards" from="1 1 1" to="0.1 0.1 0.1" dur="1500"></a-animation>
      </a-entity>
    </a-entity>
  </a-entity>

  <a-entity position="-3.5 1 0">
    <a-entity mixin="cube red">
      <a-animation begin="click" attribute="position" from="0 0 0"
                   to="0 0 -10" dur="2000" fill="both"></a-animation>
    </a-entity>
  </a-entity>

  <a-entity position="0 1 0">
    <a-entity mixin="cube green">
      <a-animation begin="click" attribute="rotation" to="0 360 0"
                   easing="linear" dur="2000" fill="backwards"></a-animation>
    </a-entity>
  </a-entity>

  <a-entity position="3.5 1 0" rotation="0 45 0">
    <a-entity mixin="cube blue">
      <a-animation begin="click" fill="forwards" repeat="1"
                   direction="alternate" attribute="position" from="0 0 0"
                   to="15 0 0" dur="2000"></a-animation>
    </a-entity>
  </a-entity>

  <a-entity position="0 3 0" class="clickable" mixin="cube yellow"
            rotation="0 45 0" scale=".5 .5 .5"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using @ngokevin [aframe-event-set-component](https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-event-set-component). It's an A-Frame component to:

> register event listeners that set properties. Replacement for old undocumented Declarative Events API.

This created the functionality that I needed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to sort of work, but if you want hover effects rather than click, change the `begin` attribute to point to a different event name.

```
<a-entity position="3.5 1 0" rotation="0 45 0">
    <a-entity mixin="cube blue">
      <!-- Mouse-enter hover. -->
      <a-animation begin="mouseenter" fill="forwards" repeat="1"
                   direction="alternate" attribute="position" from="0 0 0"
                   to="15 0 0" dur="2000"></a-animation>
    </a-entity>
  </a-entity>
```

Comment: Thanks @ngokevin. In particular I want to replicate the cubes changing to magenta on hover/fuse over and return to their original colour on hover/fuse out. In the existing codepen, I can see the `cube-hovered` mixin, but I don't see where it gets applied to the cubes.